# How to apply styles for appended element?

Tags: javascript

I'm really surprised. I have a simple script that converts HTML-code to DOM Element and appends it to the specified container. The appended element looks like other childs, BUT has no styles!

Why is it so and how to apply styles to the new element?

```js
function htmlToDOM(html)
{
    let parser = new DOMParser();
    return parser.parseFromString(html, "text/xml").documentElement;
}

let code = '<div class="red">Red</div>';

let element = htmlToDOM(code);
let container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
container.appendChild(element);
```

```css
.red {
background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="red">Red</div>
</div>
```

Running on WebKit.

Comment: jQuery allows you to add HTML to DOM ($.append()), https://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: I need to use DOM element here, for some purposes

Comment: Create a runnable [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: @charlietfl done

Comment: Interesting, in Chrome on Mac it has the unexpected behavior you mention, but if you try in firefox 56.0.2 on Mac it works as expected.  It appears that DomParser is still an experimental feature, mozilla gives the following way to parse DOM elements:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Add-ons/Code_snippets/HTML_to_DOM